# Selector tag with defaultvalue problem (JSX)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

The defaultValue property in the selector tag doesnt work as intended. I have a form component with some fields and some selector fields. Now i need to prepopulate the form when the edit button is pressed from another component. I pass the data with `this.props.history.push({
            pathname: "/Register",
            prePopulate: res.data.data
          });`

and i access the data with this.props.location.prePopulate.

I set the new values to the state and the form fields load with the previous data. The problem is with the selectors that dont show the previously chosen options. I tried with the defaultvalue property and pass the this.state.value value but it doesnt work. If i hardcode an option it works but not when it tried to pull from state.

```
<select
                        className={classnames("form-control form-control-sm", {
                          "is-invalid": this.state.valEmergency
                        })}
                        name="emergency"
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        defaultValue={this.state.emergency}
                      >
                        <option value="">Choose your level</option>
                        <option value="PRIMARY">Primary</option>
                        <option value="SECONDARY">Secondary</option>
                        <option value="TERTIARY">Tertiary</option>
                      </select>
```

Comment: try to use forceUpdate() or key attribute for select tag that will re render

Comment: i have added a console.log(this.state) command inside the render function and the state prints 2 times. First time is empty then the component will mount updates the state so the second time the state is filled with the correct values. So I rerender 2 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just go with the value property and handle the changes with `onChange={this.onChange}`. So instead of `defaultValue={this.state.emergecy}` go with `value={this.state.emergency}`

Comment: If i add the ```value={this.state.emergecy}``` then i cant choose a different option from the dropdown.It displays the prepopulate option but I cant choose another.

Comment: I had a different name than the state value...Now it works with the value property!!! Thanks a lot guys!